# Custom Password textbox C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to implement a custom password textbox in C# application.
.NET by default provides me with these properties.

```
 - PasswordChar
 - UseSystemPasswordChar
```

However the above options wont work for me as I want to implement a custom password textbox which will allow me to enter alphanumeric characters but behaves in a way similar to Android textbox controls. i.e. **I have to display the character entered for a few milliseconds** before masking it using "**asterix**" or any other password character.

To implement this, I'm handling this way currently but I think it's not the optimal solution.

```
private void txtPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (timer == null)
        {
            timer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerCallback, null, 500, 150);
        }
        int num = this.txtPassword.Text.Count();
        if (num > 1)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(this.txtPassword.Text);
            s[num - 2] = '*';
            this.txtPassword.Text = s.ToString();
            this.txtPassword.SelectionStart = num;
        }
    }

    public void Do(object state)
    {
        int num = this.txtPassword.Text.Count();
        if (num > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(this.txtPassword.Text);

            s[num - 1] = '*';
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.txtPassword.Text = s.ToString();
                this.txtPassword.SelectionStart = this.txtPassword.Text.Count();
                if (timer != null)
                {
                    timer.Dispose();
                }
                timer = null;
            }));
        }
    }
```

With this snippet called in the Constructor

```
timerCallback = new TimerCallback(Do);
```

Pretty much sure this can be done more easily or efficiently. Any inputs highly appreciated.

Thanks 
VATSAG

Comment: I would avoid creating a Thread.Sleep in the code. Rather start a timer when there is a key press, and when the timer ticks, set the asterix.

Comment: @OddmarDam : I have edited the code now. Please check. I have not used the Thread.Sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

There was an issue with the very first character that didn't get changed before you typed in the next one, but i will leave that to you for debugging :) ;)

Instead of using the System.Threading.Timer, i used the Windows.Forms.Timer

Much simpler :)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 250;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;

        int num = this.txtPassword.Text.Count();
        if (num > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(this.txtPassword.Text);

            s[num - 1] = '*';
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.txtPassword.Text = s.ToString();
                this.txtPassword.SelectionStart = this.txtPassword.Text.Count();
            }));
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = this.txtPassword.Text.Count();
        if (num > 1)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(this.txtPassword.Text);
            s[num - 2] = '*';
            this.txtPassword.Text = s.ToString();
            this.txtPassword.SelectionStart = num;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is how do I now get the actual password text ? if I query the txtPassword.Text, i get the asterix's. I should maintain a temp variable or is there any other alternative ?

Comment: That is where the security question comes in. You have to maintain a local variable with the original password.

Comment: If you are pleaced with the answers you'we gotten. pleace remember to mark them as answerd and upvote.!

Comment: I'm breaking my head here. Should I use the keypress to hold the local variable here or could you help in updating the variable in either of these methods

Comment: You know what the typed character is, add it to a local variable before you replace it with a asterix

Comment: Thanks, a minor issue remains. The cursor keeps shifting to the end of the textbox text. Any ideas what might be happening

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's generally not a good idea to implement custom security controls, unless you 100% know what are you doing. If you were using WPF, you could have nice and convinient way to preview the password with [password reveal button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.ispasswordrevealbuttonenabled.Aspx) of PasswordBox control.

Your existing code can be improved in many ways, most obvious are:

1. Replace

   if (str.Length == 1) ...

with

```
((TextBox)sender).Text=new string('*', str.Length);
```

2. Use Environment.NewLine instead of '\n'. (Why you need to store it in password array at all?)
3. Use boolean variable inside event handler to disable it's logic instead of attaching\detaching event handler every time.
4. Use Timer instead of blocking UI thread with Thread.Sleep()

Comment: Thanks I have edited my code accordingly and it works :)  Please check if there is any other things I'm missing